# Accessing memory causes system to freeze

Tags: c, module, kernel, driver

I'm trying to read the values from memory of a process according to their [vma's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW19f.jpg). However, whenever I try to access these locations en masse the system hangs and then crashes.

```
void print_mmap(struct vm_area_struct *mmap)
{ 
        while (mmap != NULL)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "vm_start: %lu vm_end: %lu difference: %lu\n", mmap->vm_start, mmap->vm_end, (mmap->vm_end-mmap->vm_start));
            int i;
            for (i=0;mmap->vm_start<mmap->vm_end;i++)
            {
                (unsigned long*) (mmap->vm_start+i);
            }
            mmap = mmap->vm_next;
        }
}
```

Why would this happen? I use rcu_read_lock() and task_lock() prior to calling the function. If I print just one value or a few values from memory then the driver runs just fine, it appears to hang only when I access from beginning to end. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was causing an infinite loop.

for (i=0;mmap->vm_startvm_end;i++)

Needed to be

for (i=0;i < (mmap->vm_end-mmap->vm_start);i++)